# How do you manually install an Active-X control to be used by Internet Explorer?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, dll, activex

I have the cab file which contains an OCX file, a DLL file, and a setup.inf file.

An example of the inf file would be
*; INF for whatever
[version]
signature="$CHICAGO$"
AdvancedINF=2.0

[Add.Code]
abc.ocx=abc.ocx
xxx.dll=xxx.dll
[abc.ocx]
file-win32-x86=thiscab
Clsid={X12AB12A-EE1E-312C-C123-0BC50DE7E01E}
RegisterServer=Yes
FileVersion=1,2,3,4

[xxx.dll]
file-win32-x86=thiscab
RegisterServer=No
FileVersion=1,2,3,4*

When I try to register either file I get the message that "DllRegisterServer" was not found in the files. I assume these are ActiveX controls for use within Internet Explorer, but the message seems otherwise.

Comment: What are you trying to install? Where did it come from?

Comment: Chart controls to display data on a website. I've tried to manually install ActiveX controls before, and I have always had the same problem, but several websites say you should be able to register them manually.

Comment: I mean specifically, not generically.